# How to get the chip name and the addressable memory in the specified architectures (x86, pic controller)?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, architecture, processor

How to get the chip name and the addressable memory in the specified architectures (x86, x64, pic controller) without bios? Have you got specific register which is storage the available memory size?

Comment: What? You expect there to be a single solution for two super-wide families of desktop/server/handheld processors, *and* a range of tiny microcontrollers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relavant this is but it may help point you in the correct direction.

Using PicBasic with PicAxe mcu's (not PIC mcu's) there was a keyword/statement in the programming language called "READSILICON"

And this READSILICON action would read an unspecified area of the silicon and return a value that in turn is/was used to identify the MCU.

So maybe in your development IDE there is a similar feature?

NOTE:
As this was a newish feature then, only the newer mcu's supported it and obviously the older ones did not.

Answer (score 0):

In x86, the chip name can be retrieved using the `CPUID` instruction; the [Wikipedia article on CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D80000001h%3a_Extended_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) gives example code for how to query the processor brand name string.

For the main reference on CPUID, see [Intel's App Note](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.html), the brand string identification is section 7.2 as of this writing.

In GCC inline assembly, you can do:

```
unsigned int cpuid = 0x80000000;

__asm__ __volatile__("cpuid\n\t" : "+a" (cpuid));
if (cpuid >= 0x80000004) { // brand name query supported
    union { char brandstr[48]; unsigned int i[12] } i;
    __asm__ ("cpuid\n\t"
        : "=a"(i.i[0]), "=b" (i.i[1]), "=c"(i.i[2]), "=d"(i.i[3])
        : "a"(0x80000002));
    __asm__ ("cpuid\n\t"
        : "=a"(i.i[4]), "=b" (i.i[5]), "=c"(i.i[6]), "=d"(i.i[7])
        : "a"(0x80000003));
    __asm__ ("cpuid\n\t"
        : "=a"(i.i[8]), "=b" (i.i[9]), "=c"(i.i[10]), "=d"(i.i[11])
        : "a"(0x80000004));
    printf ("This CPU brand name is: %48s\n", i.brandstr);
} else {
    printf ("This x86 CPU doesn't support brand name queries\n");
}
```

Determining memory layout / sizes *without* BIOS on x86 machines is well-nigh impossible as much of the way to do this directly on hardware is very specific to CPU/chipset combinations, and the vendors' development guides (BKCD - BIOS and kernel developer guide) usually only provides *partial* references about this in the public (no NDA required) version. The documented way is to query the ACPI BIOS for this information.